# Trigger not working in BulkCopy in Sql Server

Tags: c#, sql-server, triggers, sqlbulkcopy

I have an application through which I'm inserting bulk records into a table using SqlBulkCopy.
I have a trigger which inserts the records added into the First table into Another table.

When I'm inserting i have written SqlBulkCopyOptions.FireTriggers in C#, but its not working with Sql Server 2005. When worked with SqlServer2008 its working fine.

In Sql server 2005, Whenever the records are inserted into the First Table only one record from the INSERTED rows appear in the second table.

Can I manage this using Sql Server alone?

Comment: Is the trigger disabled? Have you confirmed that it works "normally"?

Answer (score 0):

One option here would be to bulk-copy into a staging table (a second, simple table - not part of the main data model; usually no indexing / constraints / triggers / etc), and then issue a `SELECT`-based `INSERT` to get the data from the staging table into the main transactional table. This allows you to get the bandwidth advantages of `SqlBulkCopy`, but still have full SQL-Server functionality for the final `INSERT`.

Comment: We cannot make any changes in the application as we don't have the source code with us now. Is it possible to implement any alternative with Sql alone and not with the application?

Comment: @smilu in that case, all I can suggest is: don't use SQL Server 2005. Given that 2005 is (in software terms) very old now, is this a genuine problem?